# Angular 1.6 bindings inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

Im trying to pass some parameters to my component through bindings, but unfortunately I'm not having luck in using those params in my controller, this is my code:

```
angular.module('project1').component('menu', {
    templateUrl: '/static/js/templates/menu.template.html',
    bindings: {
        rid: '@'
    },
    controller: ['Restaurant', function RestaurantListController(Restaurant) {
        console.log(this.rid);
        console.log(this);
        this.restaurant = Restaurant.get({restaurantId: this.rid});
    }]
});
```

HTML component:

```
<menu rid="1"></menu>
```

The interesting thing is that i can access the parameters in the template and when i do the 2 console log, the first one is undefined, but in the second one i can see the rid variable...so, i really don't understand what i'm missing.

Comment: add html component use

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With angular 1.6, your bindings are going to be ready on the method $onInit and not before.

If you need to re-enable auto bindings
https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-6-is-here#re-enabling-auto-bindings

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still searching for solution, use $onInit method provided by [angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

```
            this.$onInit = function () {
            $http.get(`/api/v1/projects`).then((res) => {
                $scope.projects = res.data;
            }, (err) => {
                $scope.error = err
            })
        };
```